# Excel: Filter for Recent Changes That Need to be Accepted

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel

I want to filter a sheet to show only rows with cells that are marked for review by the Track Changes feature. Does anyone know if/how it's possible?

Comment: Use Autofilter with proper filtering condition.

Comment: I can suggest you a method will highlight all the changes and filter them along with Sheet, Cell address and New Data to New Sheet. If this works for you just confirm through comments. ☺

Comment: @Akina, there's no filter options for the flag that Track Changes places on cells as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Rajesh, I'm open to any suggestions so fire away.

Comment: @dandalfini,, check the post, will definitely help you. ☺

Answer (score 0):

**Below written code will highlight every change and new entry in the Active Sheet and will create a Log Sheet carries Sheet name, Cell address & the entered data.**

**It's like a audit Sheet.**

**Highlighting new entries works like `Mark Track Changes` and move data to Log file is like `Filter those entries`**

*You can modify this code for further needs also.*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Boolean
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

i = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Change Log" Then
        i = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next ws
If Not i Then
   Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

   ws2.Name = "Change Log"
   ws2.Range("A1") = "Sheet"
   ws2.Range("B1") = "Range"
   ws2.Range("C1") = "New Data"
Else
   Set ws2 = Sheets("Change Log")
End If


ws2.Range("A1").Offset(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 0) = Target.Worksheet.Name
ws2.Range("B1").Offset(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 0) = Target.Address
ws2.Range("C1").Offset(ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, 0) = Target.Cells.Value

Target.Font.Color = 255

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```